# ComImport in F#

Tags: f#

I'm trying to translate some code from C# to F#, specifically the code to create a shortcut, from here: http://vbaccelerator.com/home/NET/Code/Libraries/Shell_Projects/Creating_and_Modifying_Shortcuts/ShellLink_Code_zip_ShellLink/ShellLink_cs.asp

The code in C# reads:

```
[GuidAttribute("00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
[ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComImportAttribute()]
private class CShellLink{}
```

Which I translated to F# as:

```
[<GuidAttribute("00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")>]
[<ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)>]
[<ComImportAttribute()>]
type CShellLink() = class end
```

Unfortunately, when I switch to the F# implementation, I get a runtime error of: "Method with non-zero RVA in an Import". This seems to be the same error as reported here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fsharpgeneral/thread/dada2004-5218-4089-8918-eed2464bbbcd

Is there any workaround? I'm trying to port the application to only use F#, so if this can't be written in F# that project is going to have to be rethought.

Comment: You could always write a thin wrapper in C# which then called the real function written in F# to do this

Comment: @John: Yes, but then I have to have a mixed C#/F# project, with additional build rules etc - the additional complexity cost would be pretty high.

Comment: @NeilMitchell I could swear I got this working because I was trying to do pretty much the same thing.  I'll see if I can dig up my code and I'll post it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this looks like a limitation in F# compiler: it cannot define existing COM classes using ComImportAttribute, it only works for interfaces. Can you use this as workaround?

```
let shellLink = 
    let ty = System.Type.GetTypeFromCLSID (System.Guid "00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")
    Activator.CreateInstance ty
```